# Conversion from nvarchar to float isn't working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, type-conversion

I am unable to get the following query to work due to errors upon conversion from nvarchar to float; I need to convert theData field to float in order to round it, but the data is originally an NVARCHAR(20) because the column holds character data as well. I've tried casting each of the instances of theData to float but it still didn't work, can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

```
UPDATE tblData SET tblData.theNumericData = CASE WHEN IsNumeric([theData]) = 1 
THEN Round(Convert(float, [theData]),(Len([theData])-Charindex('.',[theData]))) 
ELSE Null END 
WHERE tblData.theFlag =1;
```

I have tried the following two variants...

```
UPDATE tblData SET tblData.theNumericData = CASE WHEN IsNumeric([theData]) = 1 
THEN Round(Convert(float, [theData]),(Len(Convert(float, [theData]))-
Charindex('.',Convert(float, [theData])))) 
ELSE Null END 
WHERE tblData.theFlag =1;
```

and...

```
UPDATE tblData SET tblData.theNumericData = CASE WHEN IsNumeric([theData]) = 1 
THEN Convert(nvarchar(20),Round(Convert(float, [theData]),(Len(Convert(float, 
[theData]))- Charindex('.',Convert(float, [theData]))))) ELSE Null END 
WHERE tblData.theFlag =1;
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Yes, I've been getting the typical and consistent error.. "Error converting data type nvarchar to float."

Comment: I would suggest that you run the query `select thedata from tblData where isnumeric(thedata) = 1 order by thedata`.  In all likelihood, the problematic rows will be at the top or bottom of the list.

Comment: does convert(float,columnname) work? try one step at a time.

Comment: `IsNumeric` doesn't always catch valid numbers and sometimes includes invalid ones.

Answer (score 0):

Can't answer the question because we don't know the error you're getting but... you should move the case to where... it'll make it more readable.

```
UPDATE tblData 
SET tblData.theNumericData = Convert(float, [theData])
WHERE IsNumeric([theData]) = 1 AND tblData.theFlag =1;
```